# Remove duplicate rows SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have a table (SQL Server 2017) with sales data that contains duplicate rows, for example:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| year_id | week_id | good_id | store_id | ship_id | quantity |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2017    | 43      | 154876  | 19       | 6       | 2        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2017    | 43      | 154876  | 19       | 6       | 0        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2019    | 32      | 456123  | 67       | 4       | 6        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2019    | 32      | 456123  | 67       | 4       | 4        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2019    | 32      | 456123  | 67       | 4       | 0        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2018    | 32      | 456123  | 67       | 4       | 0        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I want to delete rows that have the same **year_id**, **week_id**, **good_id**, **store_id** and **ship_id** columns, but the **quantity** is 0. For example:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| year_id | week_id | good_id | store_id | ship_id | quantity |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2017    | 43      | 154876  | 19       | 6       | 2        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 2019    | 32      | 456123  | 67       | 4       | 6        |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I found a query that can do this, but I don’t understand how to indicate that I need to delete a row with a quantity equal to 0.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY year_id ORDER BY year_id)
   FROM dbo.sales
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: please update your output as per the input updated by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deletable CTE is on the right track.  Here is one way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id) cnt
    FROM dbo.sales
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 2 AND quantity = 0;
```

This will delete every record being duplicate with regard to the five columns you mentioned and having a zero quantity.  If you want to also cater for duplicates in greater than pairs, just change the restriction on `cnt`.

Comment: `cnt >= 2` ? Probably there exist more then one duplicate.

Comment: @Serg I gave a caveat about that in my answer.  The OP's sample data given only shows pairs of duplicates, so I catered my answer towards that.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH CTE AS
(
        SELECT year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id,Quantity ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id ORDER 
        BY quantity Desc) RN
        FROM dbo.sales
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1 And Quantity = 0`

Answer (score 0):

in your case query will be like below

```
 WITH CTE AS(
       SELECT year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id ORDER BY quantity)
, count(*) as cnt
       FROM dbo.sales group by year_id, week_id, good_id, store_id, ship_id
    )
    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 and quantity=0 and cnt>1
```

if you want to only duplicate of quantity=0 then you need quantity=0 in where condition otherwise you could remove that condition from where

Comment: @GuidoG opps another condition need

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i used group by may be you didn't noticed